# Using DC-DC converter as a switch

Tags: dc-dc-converter

Making a power distribution board with a student project and currently looking at DC-DC converters. The DC-DC converters job is to convert the voltage down from the battery to several different modules, eksample step motors for driving or another set of step motors to turn the wheels.

We are also going to be using one DC-DC converter for each module.

My question is, is it wise to use DC-DC converters with enable pin to activate a spesific module when we need is powered on? initially like a switch.

PS: we are going to be activating the DC-DC converters with a microcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used that scheme when sequencing buck regulator voltages to FPGA:s, and it usually works fine. Just take care of any emf kicks if you have inductive loads.

Boost regulators on the other hand, can be a bit tricky since some regulators pass the unboosted voltage to the output when disabled.

Comment: So "biggest" problem is going to be noice, assuming the µC working perfectly, right?

Comment: @SteffenSkaraas This is what [noice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLNxvl3-CpA) means.

Comment: I don't know without looking at the design. If you have an extremely light load and large regulator capacitors, you might experience slow device turn off.